# Get xtick labels in matplotlib returns empty array?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For the following code:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ticks = ax.get_xticklabels(True)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels,True)
plt.show()
```

The set_xticklabels is working and the plot is shown as expected . But the get_xticklabels returns an empty list. Is there any way to obtain the 'default' xticklabels before they are manually set?

Comment: are you trying to get/set the major or minor labels?

Comment: @tcaswell  Ah yes, I had interpreted incorrectly to mean "Both" but actually it returns only the Minor labels. By removing that option the values are returned properly.   I still however have not figured out how to set the minor labels and to align the labels with the data.

Comment: you should not be setting the tick labels directly, it decouples your labels from your data.  Use `Locators` and `Foramatters`

Comment: @tcaswell  UR on target again.  IF you want some more points you can also add your comment to my other question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342905/how-to-create-custom-aligned-xtick-labels-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`get_xticklabels`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels) the `minor` kwarg sets if you get the major ticks (if `minor==False`) or the minor ticks (if `minor==True`).

There is a PR against the current master [#2628](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2628) which adds a `which` kwarg to get major, minor, or both.

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you need is `ax.get_xticks()`